# can I make a 3d printable hollow cylinder?

Tags: 3d-printing

I am trying to hollow out a cylinder, however I need to have a thickness in the walls and when I try to use the extrude tool, the mesh breaks. is there another method?

Comment: why not just duplicate the cylinder with `Shift`+`D` then scale it bigger and apply scale with  `Ctrl`+`A` *> Scale*. then select both cylinders and join them with `Ctrl`+`J`. have you tried that? If the cylinder has one side open, then you can just do *Add Modifier > Solidify* and adjust the thickness, then apply it.

Comment: You can extrude, accept the extrusion without moving it, and scale the result on x and y to achieve thickness. Or add a solidly modifier instead of extruding and apply the modifier.